# what does this "from" mean?

Tags: grammar

What does the bold part mean?
Thank you.

http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/closeread/2013/08/going-to-congress-obamas-best-syria-decision.html

Or it might go badly. Obama is certainly taking a risk, but that’s what the Presidency should be, and this one is worth it. The worst outcomes would involve either Congress or the President dodging this moment and its meaning. Congress might do so by constructing some legislative monstrosity, as it did during the debt-ceiling crisis, that relies on a complicated series of mechanisms that assure nothing—except that whatever happens is Obama’s fault—or too-sweeping powers. And the most disastrous thing that Obama could do is not admitting that he’s lost if he does, and bombing anyway. **Perhaps it’s too optimistic to say that today’s decision might be what keeps some future President, our country, and who knows what other nation and people from the sort of tragedy that destroys cities.** But it will certainly help, in an area where the world needs all the help it can get. And that makes this a morally important moment for the President as well.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+keep+from

Comment: This wordy sentence might make sense if you strip it down a bit: It keeps someone from doing something. Try looking up the phrasal verb _keep from._

Answer (score 2):

The outer structure looks like this:

"Perhaps it is too optimistic to say that X [is true]."

They inverted the word order from this equivalent structure:

"Perhaps to say that X [is true] is too optimistic."

They did this because otherwise "is too optimistic" would be way, way too far away from "to say".

The inner structure (X) is then

"Today's decision might be what keeps some future President, our country, and who knows what other nation and people from the sort of tragedy that destroys cities."

Given that you could read the rest of that article, I expect you can parse this sentence.

Comment: It's interesting that you take apart the rest of the sentence but don't break down the compound subject and the split phrasal verb *to keep from* which is OP's confusion.

Comment: @Jim How do we know that that bit is OP's confusion? OP merely highlights the *whole sentence* and specified no particular part.

Comment: @TrevorD: because of the mention of 'from' in the title.

Comment: @Mitch I have to confess I often overlook the title! The main question started "What does the bold part mean?", so I thought that was the question!